# How to implement a collection with a row number which needs to be persisted with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, collections

I've googled this extensively, but I couldn't find any good examples:
What collection type can I use best if I need to persist a collection with NHibernate which has a row number? I need to be able to insert, append and delete lines as well as move them up or down the list (may also drag line on position 5 tot line position 3). Is there any list that works together with a row number property? I used a List<> for persistence, but my colleague wrapped another list around it to store the items in order. I wanna get rid of that second list.

Any hints are more than welcome.

Regards, Ted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the positions start at 0 and there are no gaps you can just use an `IList<>` in code and a `<list>` in the mapping. You don't need a seperate propery for the position that way, it will be mapped with `<index column="pos"/>`. You won't need a second list or any other code for sorting then.

Otherwise use an `ICollection<>` in code an map it as `<set>` or `<bag>`. Then you'll need a property for the position which you'll have to manage yourself.

Comment: I need to manage it myself anyway, because I need to be able to rearrange the list myself (end-user).

Comment: you can rearrange with `IList<>` too: `var temp = list[i]; list[i] = list[j]; list[j] = temp;`